# Laravel - Intentando filtrar datos usando funcionalidad de los Collections

Tags: laravel, collection

Primero voy a poner un ejemplo de datos (un poco pseudocodigo)  de una colección de Laravel:

**Colección 'personajes'**

```
personajes = nombre, nivel
```

Imagínense que tengan datos como:

```
 nombre - nivel

 jose - 1
 jose - 3
 jose - 4
 angel - 3
 angel - 2
```

No he puesto **ID**, pero se sobreentiende que cada ítem tiene uno, ya que son resultados que obtengo de la BD. En este punto de la *collection* ya hice un `get()` en la query así que ya es una colección.

Entonces la idea es obtener de cada nombre el nivel mas alto, es decir,  de **jose** obtener el de nivel **4** y el de **angel** el **3**. Pero sin volver a hacer una consulta `max()` ni nada a la BD. Debe ser a partir de esta colección, no vale decir haz el *max* en el momento de traer esos datos que pintas.

```
//hago query..
//hago el ->get()... y aqui empieza la cosa
$pjs= $pjs->unique('name');
$pjs  = $pjs->map( function( $pj) {
    $pj->level = $pj->getMaxLvl();
    return $pj;
});
```

¿Qué problema tiene lo que estoy intentando? Pues que `getMaxLvl()`, lo uso para obtener el pj más alto con ese nombre, está haciendo otra query... a la bd, consumiendo y haciendo muchísimas querys. Me gustaría hacerlo en el controller sin llamar mas a la BD pues esto consume tiempo y recursos innecesarios, pero no doy con la tecla, lo mas próximo es lo que os muestro ahí arriba, pero me duele tener que hacer esas querys de más.

Método `getMaxLvl()`:

```
public function getMaxLvl(){
    $level = self::select('level')->where('name',$this->name)->orderBy('level','desc')->first()->level;
    return $level;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problema:**

> ¿Que problema tiene lo que estoy intentando?

- El problema es que al iterar usando [map](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map), los elementos se transforman en array ya que esta misma, llama internamente a [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php), por lo que no puedes utilizar las funciones que te proporciona [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

**Solucion:**

Una solucion que veo es que primero "agrupes" la coleccion para despues usar "map", y puedas pasar la coleccion para usar sus funciones.

Dentro de estas serian:

1. [firstWhere](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first-where): Para filtrar los registros segun el nivel
2. [max](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-max): Para obtener el maximo nivel de estas

De la siguiente manera:

```
# Funcion
$pjs = $pjs->groupBy('nombre')->map(function($item, $key) {
    return $item->firstWhere('nivel', $item->max('nivel'));
});
# Resultado
{
  "Jose": {
    "id": "3",
    "nombre": "Jose",
    "nivel": "4"
  },
  "Angel": {
    "id": "4",
    "nombre": "Angel",
    "nivel": "3"
  }
}
```

**Extra:**

En tal caso que no quieras agruparlos por nombre (Ya que esto lo hace la misma funcion [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)), puedes obtener la coleccion con enteros consecutivos utilizando [values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values):

```
# Funcion
$pjs = $pjs->values();
# Resultado
[
  {
    "id": "3",
    "nombre": "Jose",
    "nivel": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "nombre": "Angel",
    "nivel": "3"
  }
]
```

Cabe resaltar que la funcion "firstWhere" esta desde Laravel 5.5, por lo que en versiones anteriores solo se separia el "where" y el "first":

```
return $item->where('nivel', $item->max('nivel'))->first();
```

Comment: Aunque es preferible que muestres que resultado quieres obtener